# How to upgrade an HTC Magic (32B DEV) from Android 1.5 to latest Android?

Tags: updates, htc-magic, cyanogenmod

Last year I got a free Android phone at a Google event, and I would like to upgrade it to the latest Android version (probably with Cyanogen).

What is the quickest/safest way to do the upgrade?

It is a developer phone, so:

- The [Cyanogen instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Full_Update_Guide_-_HTC_Magic_%2832B%29) do not mention my phone.
- I have no data plan, but the above instructions say "data plan required" ([workaround](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=G1_logon_to_google_via_wifi))

HTC Magic, Model Number GDDJ-09, Build CDB56, Android 1.5, details:

```
SAPPHIRE EVT1 32B DEV S-ON G
HBOOT-1.33.3005 (SAPP20000)
CPLD-10
RADIO-2.22.19.26I
May 29 2009,14:38:09
```

Comment: I believe this isn't possible because that phone doesn't have enough memory or something like that.  Android has gotten a lot bigger since 1.5 . I'm not putting this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @Walter Cyanogen managed it, he's basically magic ;)

Comment: The workaround for "data plan required" is only for the G1 - you can't enable USB Debugging on the Magic without activating the handset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This section](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Full_Update_Guide_-_HTC_Magic_%2832B%29#Non-TMobile_32B_Magics_and_ION.2FADP2%3a_AMON_RA_Recovery) of the Cyanogen instructions seems to cover the developer Sapphire handsets

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Cyanogen have not build 2.3-Gingerbread yet but you can get Gingerbread on the MAGIC through Ginger Yoshi. Details on XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932118

Comment: Nice. I will try it on my veteran Google Ion, currently stuck on Android 1.6, and recently banned from the Android market / Google play store.