# Open source tasks app that syncs automatically with Google Tasks?

Tags: applications, to-do-list, open-source, google-tasks

Now that there is an [API for Google Tasks](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-organized-with-tasks-api.html) (tasks in Calendar), do you know a tasks app with the following features?

- Automatic sync with Google Tasks
- Open Source
- Works offline too.
- Minimalist (same featureset as Google Tasks, plus widget maybe)
- A new task can be added very quickly, without having tens of inputs to enter deadline/assignee or anything that is not available in Google Tasks anyway.
- Available for my poor Android 1.5 phone

Comment: why do you need it to be Open Source.  the Google Tasks backend isn't.  just curious.

Comment: Good question! I would love to use an Open Source backend as well! I don't own any server, so if anyone knows a free reliable todo-list service running on open source I would be very interested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Astrid is open source but you might want to check better because I'm not sure.

Comment: Astrid is [open source](https://github.com/todoroo/astrid). It is precisely everything that the OP wanted.

Comment: My bad I forgot to mention I only have Android 1.5 and Astrid's version that supports Google Tasks seems to be only available for 1.6... otherwise it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's open source but I use GTasks and I am very happy with it.  It syncs with Google Tasks, has a nice UI, and you can add a new task by just giving it a name.

-= EDIT =-

[image]

Comment: It is not open source. Also, I couldn't find a way to reorder tasks (which is possible using Google Tasks).

Comment: If you long press a task it brings up a context menu that lets you do a lot of things including reordering.

Comment: long-press just brings me "Share" and "Delete"... maybe I am stuck with an old version because I use Android 1.5?

Comment: I am posting a screenshot of what I see in my answer.

Comment: Nice! I just checked, I am not using the latest version... It says "Requires Android: 1.5 and up" but unfortunately no update in the Android market appear :-/

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: A special "Google Developer Day" Google-produced HTC Magic with id "SAPPHIRE EVT1 32B DEV S-ON G", see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/750

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! I think this works... [Shuffle for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-shuffle/)

Comment: I think so, anyways. It doesn't sync with Google Tasks, but with Tracks, which is the server software... just run the server from your home computer!